# const widget in Flutter is not allowing me to pass arguments in constructor

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to define a parameter as callback in a `StatefulWidget` widget and using that widget as const child widget in another `StatefulWidget` widget. But it is not allowing me to pass any argument with const child widget.

Here is my code snippet:

```html
Container(
  child: const LeftSidePanel(
                  checking: (value) 
                  {
                  
                  },
                ),
         ),
```

Here is the class of child widget used in above code:

```html
class LeftSidePanel extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function(bool?) checking;
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return LeftPanelWidgetState();
  }

  const LeftSidePanel({
    required this.checking,
  });
}
```

In the first code snippet, it is giving error saying "A value of type 'Null' can't be assigned to a parameter of type 'dynamic Function(bool?)' in a const constructor. (Documentation)  Try using a subtype, or removing the keyword 'const'."

Can anyone help me with this issue. How can I solve this.
Or if you can suggest me some other way of accessing const child widget data or passing data from const child widget to parent widget.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Remove the const parameter before LeftSidePanel:

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
class LeftSidePanel extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function(bool?) checking;

  const LeftSidePanel({Key? key, required this.checking}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LeftSidePanel> createState() => _LeftSidePanelState();
}

class _LeftSidePanelState extends State<LeftSidePanel> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}

class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  const Test({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: LeftSidePanel(
        checking: (value) {},
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

That's because the code of your Function is not an const, so LeftSidePanel can't be a const.

Comment: But I don't want this child widget to rebuild each time parent rebuilds. That's why const keyword is necessary to make this widget constant. If I cannot pass function as parameter to this child widget. any other idea to access child widget data, or passing data from child widget to parent under same condition i.e. with const keyword

Answer (score 0):

Removing const will probably solve your issue. I tried running your code and removing it solved it. To answer why, I guess const doesn't allow callbacks or  methods.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: LeftSidePanel(
          checking: (value) {},
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class LeftSidePanel extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function(bool?) checking;
  const LeftSidePanel({Key? key, required this.checking}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LeftSidePanel> createState() => _LeftSidePanelState();
}

class _LeftSidePanelState extends State<LeftSidePanel> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: But const keyword is necessary with this widget. I don't want to rebuild this child widget again when the parent rebuilds.

Comment: Then you'll need to lift the state up to that parent widget. Try changing your parent widget to a stateful widget. For better answers, please provide the parent widget.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a callback that is not `const` (Invalid constant value) and therefore, you should just  remove `const` that will work for you

```
           Container(
              child: LeftSidePanel(
                checking: (value) {},
              ),
           );
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know only top level functions or static functions are considered const values in dart. Thus the lambda you are passing in for `checking` is not a const value. Therefore you cannot use the const version of the constructor.
To solve this you could either not use the const version of the constructor by omitting the const keyword or pass a top level function to `checking`.